# Are all recurrence relations sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, recurrence-relations, definition

Definitions of recurrence relations online say:

> Equations that define sequences of values using recursion and initial values.
> ([WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/discrete-mathematics/recurrences/))
>
> An equation that uses recursion to relate terms in a sequence or elements in an array. ([Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/recurrence-relations/))
>
> An equation that recursively defines a sequence or multidimensional array of values, once one or more initial terms are given. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation))

WolframAlpha describes it only as a sequence, while Brilliant and Wikipedia state it can also be arrays. My teacher wasn't sure but said recurrence relations could be represented as matrices.

Are all recurrence relations sequences?

If so, can all arrays and matrices be represented as sequences?

Otherwise, what is an example of a non-matrix an non-sequence recurrence relation.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Yes the recurrence relations are sequences. A sequence is a function $f\colon \Bbb N\to \Bbb R\mid f(n)=a_n$ i.e. $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ i.e. a list of elements, meanwhile a matrix is also a collection of elements. For example, if $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix of real numbers, $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ i.e. $a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22}$.

Comment: @manooooh Thanks! Right, but does this still mean that all arrays can be represented as sequences? Also is there some way a matrix could be encoded into a sequence or array?